Calculating the Mean of a Specially Formed Probability Density Function
I have a probability density function $\operatorname{f}\left(t\right)$ with the following form:
$$
\operatorname{f}\left(t\right) \equiv
\frac{1}{t_{E}}\,\exp\left(wt^{2} -{1 \over t_{E}}\int_{0}^{t}{\rm e}^{wx^{2}}
\,\text{d}x\right)
$$

The independent variable $t$ takes positive real values, where $w$ and $t_{E}$ are both positive real numbers.
It is evident that the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of this probability density function is as follows:
$$
-\exp\left(-\frac{1}{t_E}\int_{0}^{t}\exp\left(wx^{2}\right)\,\text{d} x\right)
$$
Now, I would like to obtain the mean of $\operatorname{f}\left(t\right)$:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}t\operatorname{f}\left(t\right) \,\text{d}t
$$
Could you please determine if it is possible to derive an analytical expression for the mean, or if the mean is a special function ?.


The CDF  must increase from zero (at $t=0$) to one (at $t=\infty,$). Add the constant one to make it correct. Let's call that CDF $F(t),.$ The mean you want to find can also be calculated by $\int_0^\infty 1-F(s),ds$ but it looks like there is no closed form.
